# Bayesian online changepoint detection (modeling assumptions in recursive derivation)

Tags: time-series, bayesian, inference, change-point

I am reading *Bayesian Online Changepoint Detection* (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.3742.pdf), and I do not understand one step in the derivation of Equation $3$. For completeness, this is my derivation:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
p(r_t, \mathbf{x}_{1:t})
&= \sum_{r_{t-1}} p(r_t, r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t})
\\
&= \sum_{r_{t-1}} p(r_t, x_t \mid r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) p(r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})
\\
&= \sum_{r_{t-1}} p(x_t \mid r_t, r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) p(r_t \mid r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) p(r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})
\\
&= \sum_{r_{t-1}} p(x_t \mid r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) p(r_t \mid r_{t-1}) p(r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})
\end{align}
$$

The only way this works if is two independence assumptions are made:

1. $p(r_t \mid r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) = p(r_t \mid r_{t-1})$
2. $p(x_t \mid r_t, r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) = p(x_t \mid r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})$

The first assumption makes sense. $r_t$ is conditionally independent from the data if we know $r_{t-1}$. In other words, nothing about the data tells us about whether or not a changepoint will or will not occur. This is just prior knowledge we need to encode into our model.

What I don't understand is the second assumption. Why isn't it

$$
p(x_t \mid r_t, r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}) = p(x_t \mid r_t, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})\tag{$\star$}
$$

(Condition on $r_t$ rather than $r_{t-1}$.) I have seen a couple resources write Equation $\star$ when explaining BOCD, but the paper is pretty consistent in writing this predictive distribution as conditioned on the previous $r_{t-1}$.

Comment: My understanding is that it depends on where you consider the change-point to be happening, whether at the beginning of the time point or at the end of the time point. So essentially their $r_t$ are offset by one, which is utterly confusing.

As a disclaimer, I have worked on this for a recently published paper, in which we generalize the method to have Markov dependencies over change-point transitions (see here, Section 1 in Appendix S1: https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1006681#sec050).

Answer (score 2):

Before I start writing the answer I have to say that I love this topic but I do not like this paper you are referring to: In my opinion it is a particularly bad example of how NOT to do mathematics, statistics and science in general.

How to properly do statistics:

1. Define the random variables / their densities / the symbols, i.e. all the ingredients in a very precise way.
2. Claim things about them, cleanly prove them using rigorous mathematical equations that even a "child in kindergarden" that always keeps on asking 'why is that so?' understands.
3. Explain the results in human like words in order to make it easier to follow the weird/complicated equations.

How they do science (at least in the paper referred to above):

1. Informally describe what you want to model but do not precisly define a single symbol in a formal way.
2. Redefine some of the symbols in a way that does not at all match the informal description before and do NOT check mathematically that these two potentially different definitions actually coincide.
3. '''Prove''' complicated facts about the relations between the symbols by arguing why it should be true and/or without even giving any proof at all.

What I want to say: We do not have any reason to believe one of these sources (since there is no math in it)!

> The first assumption makes sense. $r_t$ is conditionally independent from the data if we know $r_{t-1}$.

I definitely do not believe that statement if I cannot see the maths behind that!

> Why isn't it $p(x_t|r_t, r_{t-1}, x_{...}) = p(x_t|r_t,x_{...})$?

Again, we have no reason to believe that either one (the one you state or the one in the paper) is actually true! This is a complicated relation that needs mathematical proof.

I have thought about this for quite a while (a few months ago) and I think I have figured out what they actually want to do, i.e. I have translated the second version of how not to do statistics into the first version here: https://ufile.io/2gdjvx5a. Thm. 10 states that

$$ p(r_t, x_t|r_{t-1}, x_{0:t-1}) = p(r_t|r_{t-1}) p(x_t|\underbrace{r_t}_{\text{still here!!!}}, r_{t-1}, x_{t-1-r_{t-1}:t-1}) $$

while they claim

$$ p(r_t, x_t|r_{t-1}, x_{0:t-1}) = p(r_t|r_{t-1}) p(x_t|\underbrace{ }_{\text{???}} r_{t-1}, x_{t-1-r_{t-1}:t-1}) $$

which (I guess) is simply a mistake in the paper. I tried to contact the authors but I think unfortunately, one of them already passed away and the other one did not reply. So due to the fact that they work in a "non scientific" mode, we will probably never know (we can't even know for sure what they mean with '$R_t$' because they never actually define it in a clean way!)...

Comment: The PDF you link to is great, although it will take me some time to read it carefully! That said, I'm not sure it is in the spirit of SO: [the answer should contain the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231). Can you provide a summary in your answer here for provenance?

Comment: Thought about this as well but was in a hurry eversince and will try to do so asap :-)

Comment: I agree with @lacerbi on tone. And while I agree that the paper could be more clear, I don't agree with the general criticism that they don't define anything; they define $x_t$, $\eta$, and $r_t$; while the distribution over $r_t$ doesn't have a name, I think the authors are clear what outcomes are possible. In my implementation, at each time $t$, the posterior over $r_t$ is well-behaved, i.e. sums to 1.

Comment: I agree with the comments -- while a certain degree of robust criticism is to be expected in academic circles, I strongly encourage you to modify the tone and the language rather than have someone change it for you (or risk deletion). You can express the meat of your criticisms in a more moderate tone.

Comment: @all: true, I was in a bad mood, sorry for that, fixed bad language in some places... is it better now?

Comment: It is an improvement, thanks. There's a few more things I'd be inclined to change but I believe it's probably just about within the bounds of the usual norms now.

Comment: Back to the discussion at hand. Here is my current thinking: $p(x_t \mid \cancel{r_t}, r_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{1:t-1})$ because changepoints occur between partitions or within intervals between time increments. Thus, the distribution over $x_t$ cannot depend on $r_t$, a value which is not realized yet. $p(r_t \mid r_{t-1}, \cancel{\mathbf{x}_{1:t-1}})$ holds because changepoints⁠—and therefore run lengths⁠—are independent of the data.

Comment: All of this is true... but I doubt the way how you argue: I cannot see an equation where you start with $p(r_t|t_{t-1},...)$ at the left and finish with $p(r_t|r_{t-1})$ on the right. For example: The universe does obviously not expand: If I go to work today and work is 10km away then tomorrow it will still be 10km away, right? However, math tells us differently and with this math we were able to build GPD systems, lasers and computers... so, whom should we believe? The one who argues or the one who does math?

Comment: Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B) = \mathbb{P}(A)$. That is an equation that starts with $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ on the left and ends with $\mathbb{P}(A)$ on the right. If I flip a coin twice and claim the outcomes are independent, that is not a mathematically provable fact; it is a modeling assumption and reflects my view of the world. Similarly, the authors have made some modeling assumptions, and my goal is to understand the math assuming those assumptions hold.

Comment: @gwg yes and no. They make assumptions but every assumption weakens the model (because it is more specialized, correct?). So wouldn't it be great if it turns out that it actually is not an assumption but naturally follows from the (precise!) definitions? Then the model would be much stronger (well, it was stronger before as well but we did not know!). This is exactly what happens: all assumptions are unnecessary, they follow from the (complex) setup.

Comment: @FabianWerner, I agree that reducing assumptions is strictly better, but I don't agree that their method is a bad way to do science any more than Roman bridge-building was bad engineering or randomized control trials is a bad way to practice medicine. Sometimes thoughtful, principled empiricism is all we have. I feel like your issue is mainly that this is not a math or stats paper. That said, if you really believe that their model can be developed more rigorously, you should try publishing it. It would be a useful contribution.

Comment: @gwg This is actually what I plan to do (see the pdf above)... unfortunately the last few percents of such a work are the ones that take the longest and I am not a paid researcher (i.e. have to do these things on a weekend basis) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the Equation 3. too.
Here is my derivation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(r_t, x_{1:t}) &= \sum_{r_{t-1}}P(r_t, r_{t-1}, x_{1:t}) \\
&=\sum_{r_{t-1}}P(r_t, x_t|r_{t-1}, x_{1:t-1})P(r_{t-1},x_{1:t-1}) \\
&\underset{a}{=} \sum_{r_{t-1}}P(r_t|x_t, r_{t-1}, x_{1:t-1})P(x_t|r_{t-1},x_{1:t-1})P(r_{t-1},x_{1:t-1}) \\
&=\sum_{r_{t-1}}P(r_t|r_{t-1},x_{1:t})P(x_t|r_{t-1},x_{1:t-1})P(r_{t-1},x_{1:t-1})
\end{aligned}
$$

Here is the explanation of a:
$$
P(A,B)=P(A|B)P(B) \\
all\ condition\ on\ event\ C,\ D, \\
P(A, B|C, D) = P(A | B, C, D)P(B|C,D)
$$
so:

$$
P(r_t, x_t|r_{t-1}, x_{1:t-1}) = P(r_t | x_t, r_{t-1}, x_{1:t-1})P(x_t|r_{t-1}, x_{1:t-1})
$$

What I don't understand is how come
$$
P(r_t | x_t, r_{t-1}, x_{1:t-1}) \underset{???}{=} P(r_t|r_{t-1})
$$

### Updated:

In https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234981/227553

> it is assumed* that whether a changepoint occurs at +1 (between  and +1) does not depend on the history of , we have (+1∣,())=(+1∣)

Then it all makes sense.